# hacer datatable con yajra y laravel

Tags: ajax, datatables, eloquent, laravel-6

estoy teniendo un problema al mostrar los datos de una consulta join en yajra, el error que me arroja es el siguente:

DataTables warning: table id=laravel_datatable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

esta es mi consulta en mi controlador

```
if(request()->ajax()) {
        dd('hola');
        $user = auth()->id();
        $queja = Queja::join("reportes","reportes.id_reporte","=","quejas.id_reporte")->where('reportes.id','=',$user)->orderBy('reportes.fecha','asc')->get();
        return datatables()->of($queja)
        ->make(true);

    }
  return view('personal.listar.listar_quejasPersonal');
```

Este es mi datatable en mi blade

```
<table class="table admin-form theme-warning tc-checkbox-1 fs13" id="laravel_datatable" width="100%" >
          <thead>
            <tr class="bg-light">
               <th class="text-center">FOLIO</th>
               <th class="">ASUNTO</th>
               <th class="">DEPTO/AREA</th>
               <th class="">NOM. TRABAJADOR</th>
               <th class="">UBICACION</th>
               <th class="">FECHA & HORA</th>
               <th class="text-right">STATUS</th>
            </tr>
         </thead></table>
```

y este es mi ajax donde muestra la informacion. Cuando yo hago la consulta de una sola tabla me muestra la información sin problema pero al hacerla con esa sentencia de consulta join me meustra el error

```
$(document).ready( function () {
       $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }
      });
      $('#laravel_datatable').DataTable({
             processing: true,
             serverSide: true,
             ajax: {
              url: "{{ route('Quejas.Lista.Personal') }}",
              type: 'GET',
             },
             columns: [
                        { data: 'folio', name: 'reportes.folio' },
                        { data: 'asunto', name: 'reportes.asunto' },
                        { data: 'depto_area', name: 'reportes.depto_area' },
                        { data: 'ubicacion', name: 'reportes.ubicacion' },
                        { data: 'fecha_vencimiento', name: 'quejas.fecha_vencimiento' },
                        { data: 'status_queja', name: 'quejas.status_queja' },
                        { data: 'nom_trabajador', name: 'quejas.nom_trabajador' }  

                      ],
            order: [[0, 'desc']]
          });


       });
```

cabe mencionar que la consulta del join que se encuentra arriba ya me a funcionado pero no usando ajax, si no, usando un foreach donde recibo los parámetros y me muestra la información de las dos tabla por eso estoy seguro de que la consulta esta bien hecha al menos eso pienso yo.

Answer (score 0):

el error estaba en el name de columns ya que estaba solicitando la tabla.atributo, pero cambien el name por  el atributo únicamente ejemplo  `{ data: 'asunto', name: 'asunto' },`

y este es el código completo de como solicitarlos

```
$(document).ready( function () {
       $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }
      });
       if (!$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#postsTable')) {
              $('#laravel_datatable').DataTable({
                     processing: true,
                     serverSide: true,
                     ajax: {
                      url: "{{ route('Quejas.Lista.Personal') }}",
                      type: 'GET',
                     },
                     columns: [
                                { data: 'folio', name: 'folio', width: '10px' },
                                { data: 'asunto', name: 'asunto' },
                                { data: 'depto_area', name: 'depto_area' },
                                { data: 'ubicacion', name: 'ubicacion' },
                                { data: 'nom_trabajador', name: 'nom_trabajador' },
                                { data: 'fecha_vencimiento', name: 'fecha_vencimiento' },
                                { data: 'status_queja', name: 'status_queja', width: '10px' },
                                {data: 'action', name: 'action', width: '10px' , orderable: false}, 

                              ],
                    order: [[0, 'desc']]
                  });

        }

       });
```

Los demás tatos que tengo en la pregunta quedan tal cual los puse solo era esa parte donde me arrojaba el error